# Google Drive .net API 1.7 beta - long http response time?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been playing with the v2 GoogleDrive .NET API (1.7.0.110).  Two weeks ago, I was getting really snappy response times from the http requests which the api created.

But this past two weeks it's been really flaky.Specifically the http calls "/drive/v2/files" and "drive/v2/files?q=[SOME_QUERY]" or "/drive/v2/files/[SOME_ID]".

My app  can make like 5 of these requests consecutively and return in less than a second, and then all of a sudden, the sixth won't return for 10-20 seconds.

Sometimes such calls fail with a 500 or 503 error. Which are usually service side errors. Is anyone else seeing this?

I also notice that around 2am eastern time when I run my tests, the response times are much better.

Out of 10 calls, maybe 1 will hang up longer than normal. But the end result is my app hanging around waiting for the http response to come back and making the app look unresponsive.

In Comparison, google's oauth calls come back extremely quickly.

--

Some code I'm using to generate the requests look like this.

```
List<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> result = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File>();

FilesResource.ListRequest request = m_GoogleDriveService.Files.List();
request.Q = "'root' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"

Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList files = request.Execute();

result.AddRange(files.Items);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have confirmed they had an infrastructure issue that was causing this. I saw the same thing. It actually came in quite handy is it helped me refine my error handling :-)

Comment: Do you have a link to that confirmation?

Comment: I was hoping some kind of infrastructure issue. Thanks much!

Comment: Still intermittently slow for me today. Though better than yesterday